# Blender: How to resize selected part of uv image in python?

Tags: python, blender, editing

I'm trying to select a part of my uv image. At blender, everything looks well, tipping "s" + "mouse resize".

*BUT* I need to do this at .py archive.

Using the script bpy.ops.transform.resize(...), however, another thing happens! Object associated to image resize, not the uv image :(

How I could do, at python, the resizing of uv image part?

My script untill now:

```
def create_score():
#adding empty object
bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
empty_obj = bpy.context.object
empty_obj.name = "score"

#adding score plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=1, location=(0.5,6.7,0))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(-8, -8, -8), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)

#adding score object1
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=0.5, location=(-6, 7.2, 0.1))
obtext1 = bpy.context.object
obtext1.name = "Score1"
obtext1.select = True
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'TEXTURED'
        area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
#adding image I want resize
bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//../../textures/arialbd.tga", directory="/home/camila/Documents/cinemaxd/PlayerXD/textures/", files=[{"name":"arialbd.tga", "name":"arialbd.tga"}], relative_path=True)
bpy.data.screens['UV Editing'].areas[1].spaces[0].image = bpy.data.images['arialbd.tga']
bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
#selecting all image
bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
```

--
This

```
# store original area type
originalArea = bpy.context.area.type
# change current area to image editor
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

#insert UV specific transforms here

#return to previouswindow for good measure ( and cleanliness )
bpy.context.area.type = originalArea
```

Do not helped too :/

Comment: what are your files you are working on, what is the input, and how should the output look like?

Comment: I'm working with Dynamic Text Display. To sum up, I want to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKO4jfAHtjk, but using python